# How to Sort Lists with string, numbers and empty strings?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, collections, android-recyclerview

**Context:**

I have a list of floors that I want to sort, to show on a recycler view in android:

**Examples of existing floors:**

```
+ 1º
+ 2º
R/C
R/C
"" -> Empty string because there is no information about it
```

**Objective**: 
    I need to sort the floor in an **desc** and **asc** way.

**Code:**
    This is my code, the problem is that there are floors with letters and empty string like you see above, and I cant do an Integer.parseInt in letters and empty strings(NumberFormatException is given). I am doing this conversion because I think I need to pass the variable to Int to order. I think I cannot do this because the floor may contain letters like you can see in the example.

```
Collections.sort(listUAs, new Comparator<ModelUA>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(ModelUA lhs, ModelUA rhs) {
                            // -1 - less than, 1 - greater than, 0 - equal, all inversed for descending
                                int floorLhs = Integer.parseInt(lhs.getFloor().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
                                int floorIntRhs = Integer.parseInt(rhs.getFloor().replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""));
                                return Integer.compare(floorIntRhs, floorLhs);
                        }
                    });
```

Can someone have a better solution ou improvement?

Comment: why -1 @Carcigenicate and why the empty edit? Theres no reason for you to downvote me

Comment: I didn't downvote. I did however remove the prefixed tab as that was causing your "context" to be formatted as code, which hindered readability.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can you help me with the question?

Comment: Strings already supply a `compare` method that allows for lexicographical comparisons afaik. Can't you just compare the strings directly? Why do you need to parse them?

Comment: Get rid of the calls to `Integer/parseInt`, then just return `floorLhs.compareTo(floorRhs)`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can you show an example? because i am not understating if I use the Collection sort our not

Comment: Is there a limited set of floors which have a string only representation?

Comment: @jose `Collections/sort` should work. Honestly, I haven't written Java regularly for a while, so I'm going off of memory. At the end of your anonymous comparator that you're giving to `sort`, just return what I mentioned in my last comment. If you give me a bit I can experiment in IntelliJ and try to write an answer.

Comment: Yes i will give you a bit. Thanks :)

Comment: And how can I put it in a reverse order to?

Answer (score 1):

Just compare the strings lexicographically. Until you have a much more complicated case, this should generally suffice.

This got verbose, but it should demonstrate what to do. Most of this was just to make a complete example. Scroll down to the call to `models.sort` for the meat of it.

```
package mandelbrot_redo.seesaw_main;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ModelUA {
    private String floor;

    public ModelUA(String floor) {
        this.floor = floor;
    }

    public String getFloor() {
        return this.floor;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Unsorted floor strings
        List<String> floorStrs =
                Arrays.asList("R/C",
                              "+ 1º",
                              "R/C",
                              "+ 2º",
                              "");

        // Wrap each floor string in a ModelUA
        List<ModelUA> models = floorStrs.stream().map(ModelUA::new).collect(Collectors.toList());

        models.sort(new Comparator<ModelUA>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ModelUA m1, ModelUA m2) {
                // Just delegate to the string compare method
                return m1.getFloor().compareTo(m2.getFloor());
            }
        });

        for (ModelUA m : models) {
            System.out.println(m.getFloor());
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
+ 1º
+ 2º
R/C
R/C
```

And to reverse the sort order, you can just swap the models in the `compareTo` line:

```
m2.getFloor().compareTo(m1.getFloor());
```